# Mock HttpPostedFileWrapper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mocking, moq

I am trying to Mock the MVC object `HttpPostedFileWrapper` so I can test the "ContentType" and "InputStream" properties in particular. I set up my mock as so:

```
var mockPostedFile = new Mock<HttpPostedFile>();
var mockFileWrapper = new Mock<HttpPostedFileWrapper>(mockPostedFile);
mockFileWrapper.Setup(file => file.ContentType).Returns("application/pdf");
mockFileWrapper.Setup(file => file.InputStream).Returns(fileStream);
```

but I get this exception on the first line:

> Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class.

If I change `HttpPostedFile` to `HttpPostedFileBase` I get this exception when I call `mockFileWrapper.Object`

> Can not instantiate proxy of class: System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper.
>   Could not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
>   Moq.Mock`1[System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase]

Does anyone know what I can do to pull this off?

Comment: Are you sure you tried `HttpPostedFileBase`?  It *only* has a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be mocking `HttpPostedFileBase`, not `HttpPostedFileWrapper`.

Comment: This change did the trick. I had to change the method I was testing to take HttpPostedFileBase instead of HttpPostedFileWrapper, but it worked fine with this change.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock a type having no public constructor such as `HttpPostedFile`.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but this does not provide a solution to the question.

Comment: @CodeGrue: You can't pull off what is totally unsupported by the framework you're using, that's it.